# Why does javac checkcast arrays twice?

Tags: jvm, bytecode, javac, jikes

Examining bytecode, I've noticed javac seems to duplicate `checkcast` instructions when casting to array types.

Cast.java:

```java
    class Cast {
      void test(Object a) {
        Object[] b = (Object[]) a;
      }
    }
```

javap disassembly of the javac compiled version

```
    void test(java.lang.Object);
      Code:
       0:   aload_1
       1:   checkcast   #2; //class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
       4:   checkcast   #2; //class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
       7:   astore_2
       8:   return
```

Testing jikes shows the expected single cast

```
    void test(java.lang.Object);
      Code:
       0:   aload_1
       1:   checkcast   #10; //class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
       4:   astore_2
       5:   return
```

`checkcast` is supposed to raise an exception if the object can't be treated as the requested type and otherwise does nothing, so I don't see why it might help to double the cast. I haven't looked at the JDK sources to see how it's produced, and if that helps explain the why (maybe it's meant as a hint).

Comment: Interesting... Discussed elsewhere: http://mail-archive.ow2.org/asm/2007-07/msg00034.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a [known bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6246854) of javac. But it is mostly harmless.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. My searches failed.

Comment: You would think it would get fixed, how hard can it be to fix !